# Is it considered bad practice to call a class function on its own attribute?

Tags: python

Can I just call the `get_random_items()` function directly on the `random_items` attribute or is this considered bad practice in Python?

```
class Items(object):

    def __init__(self, tools, toys, food):
        self.tools = tools
        self.toys = toys
        self.yellow = food
        self.random_items = self.get_random_items([self.tools, self.toys, self.food])

    def get_random_items(self, item_list)
        # do stuff to get random items..
        return random_items
```

If this is bad practice, what would be a better way to provide the `random_items`?

Comment: Explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: I thought `self.random_items` is a property? If not I should refactor the question.

Comment: I think maybe OP means if `self.random_items` (which is just the return value of the function) should just be replaced with the function. @le0m is that what you mean?

Comment: Note that a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) is something very specific in Python. Since you meant to use the term "attribute", I have edited your title.

Comment: In short: there's nothing wrong with calling a method to set an attribute. We have not enough context about what you are actually trying to do, so it is hard to tell if this particular example is good design.

Comment: I just wonder if it is ok to generate the values of attributes from within the `__init__` function or if it be better to generate the values externally and add them to the instances. Sorry I find it hard to expaint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works. But if you do that, the value of `random_items` will be calculated only one time during `__init__`. You will  always get the old value, although the values of `tools`, `toys` or `food` are currently changed.

You should use here `property`

```
class Items(object):

    def __init__(self, tools, toys, food):
        self.tools = tools
        self.toys = toys
        self.yellow = food

    @property
    def random_items(self):
        return self.get_random_items([self.tools, self.toys, self.food])

    def get_random_items(item_list)
        # do stuff to get random items..
        return some_random_items
```

And you can use `random_items` like attribute in other functions.